# XSL eliminating elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml document:

```
<tags>
<w lemme="déclaration" pos="NOM">Déclaration</w>
<w lemme="du" pos="PRP:det">des</w>
<w lemme="droit" pos="NOM">droits</w>
<w lemme="de" pos="PRP">de</w>
<w lemme="le" pos="DET:ART">l'</w>
<w lemme="homme" pos="NOM">homme</w>
<w lemme="et" pos="KON">et</w>
<w lemme="," pos="PUN">,</w>
...
</tags>
```

I'm trying to use xsl to filter out articles and punctuation. Like here < w lemme="," pos="PUN" >,< /w > and < w lemme="de" pos="PRP" >de< /w>  < w lemme="le" pos="DET:ART">l'< /w>. So I made the following stylesheet which works but generalizes all my conditions to all tags including the tag < tags>.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains(@pos,'PUN')"></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="contains(@pos,'PRP')"></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="contains(@pos,'DET')"></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:attribute name="lemme">
<xsl:value-of select="@lemme"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="pos">
<xsl:value-of select="@pos"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And I have this result:

```
<tags lemme="" pos="">
<w lemme="déclaration" pos="NOM">Déclaration</w>
<w lemme="droit" pos="NOM">droits</w>
<w lemme="homme" pos="NOM">homme</w>
<w lemme="et" pos="KON">et</w>
<w lemme="citoyen" pos="NOM">citoyen</w>
```

So it works and shows me only the lines I'm interested in, only I don't want it to also add lemme="" pos="" in the < tags > tag on the first line. What should I change in the xsl to make it only take the < w > tags. I tried < xsl:template match="w" > but it didn't produce a valid xml. Help please?

Comment: Could you reformat your question? Your code blocks are unreadable...

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, it's better now I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a standard identity transform, which is this template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You can always use this to copy everything from the source to the output. The exceptions are handled by extra templates, like this one:

```
<xsl:template match="w[contains(@pos,'PUN')]
                    |w[contains(@pos,'PRP')]
                    |w[contains(@pos,'DET')]"/>
```

which does nothing. It simply matches the unwanted elements and prevents the identity transform template from matching and copying them. The full stylesheet would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w[contains(@pos,'PUN')]
                      |w[contains(@pos,'PRP')]
                      |w[contains(@pos,'DET')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting solution based on identity transform, cutting down on the copying boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, but one way to augment what you already have is to have one rule matching and outputting the tags-element and then applying the second template matching only the w-elements

For the first bit, add this template before the one you have:

```
<xsl:template match="/tags">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="w"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For the second bit, change your current template to:

```
<xsl:template match="w">
```

For clarity, here is the complete stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/tags">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="w"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@pos,'PUN')"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@pos,'PRP')"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@pos,'DET')"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="lemme">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@lemme"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="pos">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@pos"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This yields the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tags>
    <w lemme="déclaration" pos="NOM">Déclaration</w>
    <w lemme="droit" pos="NOM">droits</w>
    <w lemme="homme" pos="NOM">homme</w>
    <w lemme="et" pos="KON">et</w>
</tags>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I do want them to be part of the output, but only in the < w> tags but it also adds the attributes in the first mother tag <tags>.

Comment: Sorry, I replied too fast and missed that detail. Updating answer.

Comment: Well, i can't really use two different < xsl:template match > because to use the attribute < choose> and < otherwise> I can't separate the two bits in different template match.

Comment: I also tried to add that block just before mine and change my current match * to "w" but the xml was not even valid

Comment: Your matching in w-elements is in no way affected by the introduction of a second template. For clarity, I've added the full stylesheet and the output an XSLT transformer yields given the input you listed.

Comment: I'm sorry, it still isn't working. I copied the code you gave me as is and the xml was not valid. I was getting errors and the page won't open. But thank You!

Comment: OK something must have gone wrong in the pasting process then because I just tested that answer on http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php and it works fine, but never mind as long as you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: Maybe it's because i'm using a java code to automatically generate the xml and include the stylesheet. Something might've gone wrong with that. It seems to be working with everything else though. It just never worked when i tried template match="w" before. I never got the xml page to open with that.